# Reading a file for each word and sorting those words with a Binary Search Tree (Lexicographically)

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list, binary-search-tree, lexicographic

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm working on an assignment that requires us to read a file and take each word from that file and sort it in a table that displays the word and the line number it exists on.

example:

File that get's read contains:

```css
this is a
text file is
```

So it will output the following:

```css
a       1
file    2
is      1   2
text    2
this    1
```

So it takes each word and then sorts it alphabetically and then also prints what lines it appears on. I've got this code so far(**EDITED**):

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode{
        string word;               //word will store the word from text file
        vector<int>lines;          //for keeping record of lines in which it was found
        TreeNode*left;             //pointer to left subtree
        TreeNode*right;            //pointer to right subtree
        TreeNode*temp;
    }; //end TreeNode

//check function for comparing strings
bool check(string a,string b)
{
    if(a<b)
      return false;
    return true;
}//end check

void insert(TreeNode *root,string word,int lineNumber){
    //Tree is NULL
   if(root==NULL){
      root=new TreeNode();
      root->word=word;
      root->lines.push_back(lineNumber);
   }//end if
    //words match
   if(root->word==word)
      root->lines.push_back(lineNumber);

   //check(a,b)is function that returns 1 if 'string a' is bigger than 'string b' lexographically
   if(check(root->word,word)){ //present word is lexographically bigger than root's word
      if(root->right)          //if right node to root is not null we insert word recursively
        insert(root->right,word,lineNumber);
      else{                    //if right node is NULL a new node is created
        TreeNode*temp=root->right;
        temp=new TreeNode();
        temp->word=word;
        temp->lines.push_back(lineNumber);
     }//end else
    }//end if
    else{ //present word is lexographically smaller than root's word
      if(root->left)
        insert(root->left,word,lineNumber);
      else{
        TreeNode*temp=root->left;
        temp=new TreeNode();
        temp->word=word;
        temp->lines.push_back(lineNumber);
      }//end nested else
    }//end else
}//end insert

//Print tree in In-Order traversal
void InOrder(TreeNode* node)
{
    if(!node) //end if pointing to null
        return;
    InOrder(node->left);        //display the left subtree
    cout << node->word << " ";  //display current node
    InOrder(node->right);        //display the right subtree
}//end InOrder

int main() { //main
 //int lineNumber = 0; //number of lines
 ifstream file("text.txt"); //takes input stream from designated file
 if(file) { //if file is there
  string line, word ; //setting line and word strings
  while(getline(file, line)) { //getting the lines from the file
            //++lineNumber; //incrementing number of lines when a new line is read
   istringstream is(line); //checking for a line
   while(is >> word) { //while a word exists
    InOrder(root); //<< lineNumber << "\n"; //outputting the words and tabbing to then print the line number and then a new line
   }//end word while
  }//end getline while
 }//end file if
 file.close();
 file.clear();
 return 0;
}//end main
```

my current output:

```css
this    1
is      1
a       1
text    2
file    2
is      2
#
```

(The # character just shows it's the end of the table)

But I've never built a tree before and was also thinking of having the tree search the file first and put each word in an alphabetical linked list. Then searching that linked list for duplicates of the word and sending that to a nested linked list to print out the line numbers of the original word and the duplicates.

I am just looking for help on this assignment, I'm really confused by it, don't find myself to be a great programmer yet and that's why I'm in school! Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Please don't post images of text, especially as links that can disappear and make your question totally worthless. Instead copy-paste the text, *as text* into the body of the question. Please edit your question to include the input and output. Also please include the *actual* output of your program, so we can compare it with the expected output. And if you haven't done it yet, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If your code works you may want to ask for a code review or inspection next door at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating the problem. If I were you, I would define a struct like

```
struct Whatever
{
    string word;
    vector<int> line;
};
```

and declare a `vector<Whatever> text`

After that, you could use the algorithm `sort` with a custom compare function that would sort your `text` vector in lexicographic order.

If you really have to use binary search trees for the assignment, take some time and do some research. The basic idea is that every time you want to insert a node in the tree, you compare it with the current node (which at beginning will be the root) and see if it's greater or lesser in value (in your case, lexicographic compare) and go in the specified direction (left for lesser, right for greater) until you reach a NULL node and there you add it. After that, you can gen a lexicographic order by doing a `left-root-right` parse of the tree. Again, I would use that `struct` for ease.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the structure you should use along with insert function to implement the problem using binary tree-

```
struct TreeNode{
        string word;               //word will store the word from text file
        vector<int>lines;     //for keeping record of lines in which it was found
        TreeNode*left;             //pointer to left subtree
        TreeNode*right;            //pointer to right subtree
    };
```

In your case, you were including this structure in a `class LexTree` which isnt of much help but instead complicates things.

Here's how you should implement insert function-

```
TreeNode* insert(TreeNode *root,string word,int lineNumber)
{
    //Tree is NULL
   if(root==NULL){
      root=new TreeNode();
      root->word=word;
      root->lines.push_back(lineNUmber);
   }
    //words match
   else if(root->word==word)
      root->lines.push_back(linenumber);

   //check(a,b)is funtion that returns 1 if 'string a' is bigger than 'string b' lexographically
   else if(check(root->word,word)){//present word is lexographically bigger than root's word
      if(root->right)         //if right node to root is not null we insert word recursively
        root->right=insert(root->right,word,lineNumber);
      else{                   //if right node is NULL a new node is created
        Node*temp=new TreeNode();
        temp->word=word;
        temp->lines.push_back(lineNumber);
        root->right=temp;
     }
    }
    else{ //present word is lexographically smaller than root's word
      if(root->left)
        root->left=insert(root->left,word,lineNumber);
      else{
        Node*temp=new TreeNode();
        temp->word=word;
        temp->lines.push_back(lineNumber);
        root->left=temp;
      }
    }
}
```

**EDIT-**

Here is your check function-

```
bool check(string a,string b)
{
    if(a>b)
      return false;
    return true;
}
```

To use `insert` just pass `root node of your BST` along with your `word` as arguments to `insert`

Some tweaks in InOrder and main that should solve the problem

```
//Print tree in In-Order traversal
void InOrder(TreeNode* node)
{
if(!node) //end if pointing to null
    return;
InOrder(node->left);        //display the left subtree
cout << node->word << " ";  //display current node



for(int i=0;i<node->lines.length();i++)  //vector lines contains all the line numbers where we had the word node->word
     cout<<nodes->lines[i]<<" "; 

 cout<<endl;


}//end InOrder

int main() { //main
//int lineNumber = 0; //number of lines


TreeNode *root=NULL;   //you need to declare root to make a BST


ifstream file("text.txt"); //takes input stream from designated file
if(file) { //if file is there
    string line, word ; //setting line and word strings
    while(getline(file, line)) { //getting the lines from the file
        //++lineNumber; //incrementing number of lines when a new line is read
        istringstream is(line); //checking for a line
        while(is >> word) { //while a word exists


            root=insert(root,word);  // insert word in your BST


        }//end word while
    }//end getline while


  Inorder(root);   //gives required output


}//end file if
file.close();
file.clear();
return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: So then with this I would call the insert function in main after it reads the file and before the cout statement?

Comment: Well i also have to create the check function that will be getting called into the insert, but then call insert upon the main getting the word?

Comment: @RileyKennedy i have added answer to your question in the new edit

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using insert. once the tree is made the in-order traversal has to be printed to get the words in alphabetical order. but the program also has to take duplicates into account and instead of reprinting the duplicates it just prints the line numbers that it is on

Comment: so i've edited the original post to now contain all of the code have so far. I need to now call the InOrder function in main when it does the first print to have it alphabetically but can't initialize it with InOrder(root) because of scope......

Comment: still getting errors like, error: 'class vector<int>' has no member named 'length'

Comment: i'm also getting an error of how InOrder was not defined in the scope of main

Comment: the insert function also has 3 arguments. it's missing one. i tried adding insert(root, word, line) but that didn't work

Comment: (1)use function .size() instead of length
(2)use `InOrder` instead of `Inorder` in main
(3)pass`insert` as `insert(root,word,linenumber)`

Comment: Yes you need `int linenumber` dont comment it

Comment: i still get a blank output, it's almost like it's not reading the file and building the tree from it >.> should the insert function also be reading the file to build the tree?

Comment: My bad, it happened because function makes a copy of variables which it deletes on exiting as a result of which root is not updated. So I am returning new values and saving them in new code of insert, check and main.`check` is updated due to silly mistake on my part due to which result is shown in opposite order(try both to know what i mean)